# Variable to track current node location of agent

Tags: anylogic

I've set up a variable v_palletCurrNode that I want to change to the name of the current node the pallet is at. But when I run the model, the variable is remaining null after moving through the source block, even though I specified the variable to change. The node the pallets are sourced into is called Dock. Any advice?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating the creation of pallets. The Source block creates them and you manually also create them via `add_Pallets()`.

Your `agent. ...` code refers to the pallet created by the source, you likely check the wrong agent that you created.

Ensure you understand what your blocks are doing, and what each line of code you write is doing (`add_...` is an advanced method you likely don't yet know how to wield :) )

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I've removed the population of agents. Under the Source block I have On exit: agent.v_palletCurrNode = Dock; but this still does not seem to change the variable. Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: you are probably still checking it wrong, try it manually, step by step or simplify it further. Might also be that the Dock isn't there... the approach is correct, hard to say where the root cause is. Put on the Sherlock hat and investigate until you find it :)